# .NET when grouping records by hour impossible to use datetime in the select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, request

I'm trying to group a list of records by hour and store the number of record for each hour. Here is my code :

```
        DateTime firstTimeStamp = myRecords.DataBaseRecords.First().TimeStamp;
        Statistics = myRecords.DataBaseRecords
         .GroupBy(x => x.TimeStamp.Hour)
          .Select(group => new GraphModel() { Date =firstTimeStamp.AddHours(group.Key), Value = group.Count() })
        .ToList();
```

The problem is that when I'm on the select fuction, I cannot acces to the DateTime anymore so the field group.key contains a value between 0 and 24. I just need to group all the records by hour and foreach hour, I need to have the number of records in the Value parameter.

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: It actually doesn't return a hour bigger than 24 so if for example the next datetime is in 3days, it wont return 82hour but will return 0 :/

Comment: What do you expect from it? When you take an hour it will return a value from 0 to 23. The date is a separate value.

Comment: yes but i cannot obtain the date in the select if I did use a groupby hour

Comment: Rather than `x.TimeStamp.Hour`, use `(int)Math.Truncate(x.TimeStamp.TotalHours)`.

Comment: @KingOfBabu: You can get the date from the first item in the group.

Comment: TimeStamp is a Datetime field not a timeSpan, so TotalHours doesn't work

Comment: And a day consists of 24 hours, so you'll never get an `Hour` value larger than 24. You'll need to get elapsed time, either by converting your timestamps to elapsed time (so the earliest time stamp will be 00:00:00), or by doing the subtraction as suggested by Gert Amold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group the data by absolute hours as of the first timestamp, i.e. the differences in hours calculated for each `TimeStamp` value:

```
Statistics = myRecords.DataBaseRecords
                      .GroupBy(x => DbFunctions.DiffHours(firstTimeStamp, x.TimeStamp) into g
                      .Select(g => new GraphModel
                      {
                          Date = g.FirstOrDefault().TimeStamp,
                          Value = g.Count()
                      };
```

If this is plain LINQ to objects (not Entity Framework) you can replace ...

```
DbFunctions.DiffHours(firstTimeStamp, x.TimeStamp)
```

... by

```
(x.TimeStamp - firstTimeStamp).TotalHours
```

If it's LINQ to SQL, use

```
SqlMethods.DateDiffHour(firstTimeStamp, x.TimeStamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this may work out for you:

```
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Parse(firstTimeStamp).AddHours(group.Key).Ticks);
```

Question specific to answer above:

```
 ...Date = new DateTime(DateTime.Parse(firstTimeStamp).AddHours(group.Key))...
```